# Contradiction? Differentiation product rule and "Limit of product is the product of limits"

Tags: limits, derivatives

I don't understand why it's not a contradiction:

On one hand, we have the product rule for differentiation:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(f\cdot g) = \dfrac{df}{dx} \cdot g + f\cdot \dfrac{dg}{dx}$$

on the other hand, we have rule for the limit of a product:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} [f(x)\cdot g(x)] = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)⋅\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)$$

I think I got confused with the Leibniz notation... I thought that:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$$

Comment: That's **not** the formula for differentiation. Better hit the books!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality you mention at the end of the question

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$$ is not true.

What is true by definition of the derivative is

$$f^\prime(a)= \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ and if $f^\prime$ is continuous at $a$

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(a) =f^\prime(a)= \lim\limits_{x \to a} f^\prime(x).$$

In any case there is no conflict with the product rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's not the definition of the derivative. It's a bit more complicated:

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to x} \frac{f(x) - f(h)}{x-h}$$

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that:
>
> $$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$$

You most certainly thought wrong. Take, for example, $f(x)=x$. Then, $$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = 1$$ while $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = a$$

so what you wrote is completely wrong.

---

The definition of the derivative is

$$(\frac{d}{dx}f)(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$